# Aligning a rectangle on a canvas dynamically

Tags: c#, wpf, canvas, diagram

I want to add several `Rectangle` to a `Canvas`. To do so I made a method that:

- sets height and width
- sets color
- sets canvas position
- adds it to `myCanvas.Children`

As parameter for that method I have a double that defines the vertical position. Furthermore I've got an array that contains the parameters max and min value as well as a constant that defines the accuracy of displaying.

As of right now I have the accuracy set to 0.04 for 4%, that means if i have min set to 0 and max to 1 the `Canvas.Top` should be 0 if the parameter is .52 and `Canvas.Height` (max) if it is at .48.

Thats what I got so far... (data[1] = min, data[2] = max, accuracy = 0.04, val = parameter)

```
Canvas.SetBottom(rec,Math.Floor((val- ((data[2]-data[1])/2) + (data[2]-data[1])*accuracy/2)/(data[2]-data[1])*accuracy*diagramCanvas.Height));
```

And a second attemp..

```
Canvas.SetBottom(rec, Math.Floor((val-(data[2]*(.5-(accuracy*.5))))*25*diagramCanvas.Height));
```

My question is:
What did I do wrong or where do i have to change my code?
Thanks in advance

Complete Method:

```
private Rectangle GetRectangle()
{
        rec = new Rectangle();
        rec.Width = 1;
        rec.Height = 1;
        rec.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
        Canvas.SetLeft(rec, diagramCanvas.Width);
        //works for min 0 and max 1
        //Canvas.SetBottom(rec, Math.Floor((val-(data[2]*(.5-(accuracy*.5))))*25*diagramCanvas.Height));
        Canvas.SetBottom(rec,Math.Floor((val- ((data[2]-data[1])/2) + (data[2]-data[1])*accuracy/2)/(data[2]-data[1])*accuracy*diagramCanvas.Height));
        return  rec;
}
```

Comment: Can you post the complete code for your method?

Comment: I've addet the complete method now

Comment: Thanks, still havent quite got a handle on what youa re trying to achieve.  What output would you expect with the edge cases value=0 and value=1 with min=0, max=1, accuracy=0.04?

Comment: Might have confused that a bit, sorry.. while min = 0 and max = 1 the parameter will be within the accuracy range of 4%... that means the value will be between 0.48 and 0.52. If the value is out of that accuracy range it won't be used, to make it easier.

Comment: How about  (((min+max+accuracy)/2)-val) * canvasHeight / accuracy  ? - this gives an output of 0 with val=0.52 and canvasHeight with val=0.48

Comment: That seems right but for some reason it does not work out for me. There is no Rectangle getting displayed...

Comment: That might be due to my code having a bug somewhere.. the formula is great, thanks :D